# Open menu using redux

Tags: react-redux, react-navigation

I am trying to open a menu by dispatching an action, using `react-navigation`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Image, TouchableHighlight, View } from 'react-native';

import { navigate } from './actions.js'

class HeaderLeft extends Component {

 constructor(props) {

        super(props);
        this.showMenu = this.showMenu.bind(this);
  }

  showMenu() {
   this.props.dispatch(navigate('DRAWER_OPEN'));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.showMenu()}>
          <Image source={require('../images/home-icon.png')}  style={{width: 30, height: 30}} />
        </TouchableHighlight>

      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default connect()(HeaderLeft);
```

I am using redux, I get the error `cannot read property 'navigate` of undefined

I am importing my actions file below:

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

export const navigate = (routeName, params, action) =>
  NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName, params, action });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`actions` is undefined since you do not export anything by default in your file `action.js`. The correct import should be

```
import { navigate } from './actions.js';
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, now I get the error, undefined is not an object (evaluating '_actions.actions.navigate')

Comment: Your error is that you import `{ actions }` instead of  `{ navigate }`.
Then you need to call it like this : `this.props.dispatch(navigate('DRAWER_OPEN'));`.